# In NHibernate ID Generator section in mapping files, What is the meaning of assigned and select?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, id-generation

In `NHibernate` ID Generator section in mapping files, What is the meaning of assigned and select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's identity/sequence and assigned. From the NH [documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html):

> **5.1.5.1. generator**
>
> For databases which support identity
>   columns (DB2, MySQL, Sybase, MS SQL),
>   you may use identity key generation.
>   For databases that support sequences
>   (DB2, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Interbase,
>   McKoi, SAP DB) you may use sequence
>   style key generation. Both these
>   strategies require two SQL queries to
>   insert a new object.
>
> uid_sequence
>             
>             For cross-platform development,
>   the native strategy will choose from
>   the identity, sequence and hilo
>   strategies, dependent upon the
>   capabilities of the underlying
>   database.
>
> **5.1.5.7. Assigned Identifiers**
>
> If you want the application to assign
>   identifiers (as opposed to having
>   NHibernate generate them), you may use
>   the assigned generator. This special
>   generator will use the identifier
>   value already assigned to the object's
>   identifier property. Be very careful
>   when using this feature to assign keys
>   with business meaning (almost always a
>   terrible design decision).
>
> Due to its inherent nature, entities
>   that use this generator cannot be
>   saved via the ISession's
>   SaveOrUpdate() method. Instead you
>   have to explicitly specify to
>   NHibernate if the object should be
>   saved or updated by calling either the
>   Save() or Update() method of the
>   ISession.

Answer (score 7):

`assigned` means that you assign the primary key in code before saving the entity in the session.

`select` means it is assigned by the database, and it's obtained from the database by querying on some unique key.